# Why SVM classifier generates bad results with LDA in Classification of audio data?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svm, libsvm

I am using SVM classifier to classify my audio data (instrument strokes). I am using LDA as a feature reduction technique to reduce feature dimensions. After applying classifier the results I am getting is very low (only 45% accuracy). 
With the same data without any feature reduction and using PCA I am able to get more than 90% accuracy.
What may be the problem?

Comment: Are you evaluating performance using cross-validation?

Comment: What are your input features to the classifier?